# How do I detect the first time a ClickOnce-deployed application has been run?

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce-deployed application and I'm currently using this to detect the first time a new deployment is being run:

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
    && ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun)
{
    // Display release notes so user knows what's new
}
```

It seems to works as expected after ClickOnce performs an automatic update.

But it doesn't work at all when the user goes to publish.htm on the install site and installs a newer version manually.  Is there a way to detect *both* of these conditions reliably?

**Edit:** The situation I'm trying to account for: sometimes users hear that an update has been released and manually go to publish.htm to get the new version, instead of launching the application and letting ClickOnce handle the upgrade.  To ClickOnce, this is apparently indistinguishable from a first-time install.  Is that true?

**Solution Code**: I ended up creating a ClickOnce helper class with the following key section:

```
    public static bool IsFirstRun
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsNetworkDeployed)
                return false; // not applicable == bool default value

            if (!File.Exists(VersionFileName))
                return true;

            return (GetLastRunVersion() != Version.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void StoreCurrentVersion()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(VersionFileName, Version.ToString());
    }

    public static string GetLastRunVersion()
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenText(VersionFileName))
        {
            return stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    public static string VersionFileName
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder filename = new StringBuilder(Files.LocalFilesPath);
            if (!filename.ToString().EndsWith(@"\"))
                filename.Append(@"\");
            filename.Append(@"versioninfo.dat");
            return filename.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution seems a bit incomplete. Can you explain the logic? Does Version reference you assembly version? How does StoreCurrentVersion get used?

Comment: You could use Path.combine instead of a string builder in the VersionFileName property.

Comment: You should store the results of computing VersionFileName in a backing field so you don't compute it multiple times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Include an extra file in your ClickOnce install called justInstalled.txt (or something). Chedk for that file when the app starts. If you find it delete it and run any code for your first run of that deployment. The file will stay missing until the next deployment/upgrade.

Comment: So the answer is that ClickOnce has no way to distinguish between a first-install and an upgrade install?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly you want to "detect both of these conditions reliably" which isn't quiet the same as "distinguish between a first-install and an upgrade install."  From looking at the code, I think you just want to display release notes on the first run after each install.  I also got that while the code you have should work (according to MS docs), it doesn't. If I've misunderstood, let me know.

Comment: In other words: to ClickOnce, if the user goes to publish.htm and clicks install, it does not matter whether the application is already installed or not?  ClickOnce will always interpret that as a first-time install and there's no way to detect that condition like you can detect an auto-upgrade with `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun`?

Comment: Not quite. You said "always interpret as first-time install" - should be "always interpret as first run (after install or upgrade)."  Don't confuse "first run" with "first install."   IsFirstRun means is this the first time the user has run the application after a new install or upgrade (either one). It should be triggered in both scenarios, but you don't know if it was a first install or upgrade. You can't distinguish between them with IsFirstRun.

Comment: Apparently there are some outstanding bugs in IsFirstRun. Here's an example at [Microsoft's site](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/505070/clickonce-applicationdeployment-update-doesnt-reset-applicationdeployment-isfirstrun).

Comment: My question was regarding whether there is a way to also detect whether the application has just been installed for the first time, and it seems like the answer is a resounding "no."  Not only that, it even sounds like IsFirstRun is buggy according to that link (and has been since 2009...) so the method you describe above sounds like the best solution for all of the possible conditions where we want to detect when the user is running a new version for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the IsFirstRun is reset for each program version...

This is the except from Microsoft:

> The value of this property is reset
>   whenever the user upgrades from one
>   version to the next. If you want to
>   perform an operation only the very
>   first time any version of the
>   application is run, you will need to
>   perform an additional test, such as
>   checking for the existence of a file
>   you created the first time, or storing
>   a flag using Application Settings.

which more or less answers you question...

Comment: Not quite... the situation I'm describing is not the first time the application has been run on the machine -- the application is already installed, but the user upgrades manually instead of letting ClickOnce perform an automatic update.

Comment: @Calvin Fisher, I'm running into the same problem. I'm going to attempt Richard's answer above.  Seems fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    ApplicationDeployment deployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

    if (deployment.IsFirstRun)
    {
        //Your Code Here....
    }
}
```

See [IsFirstRun Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isfirstrun?view=netframework-4.7.2)