# One Click Applications, and detecting first launch of new version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, clickonce

Is there a simple way to detect the first launch of a new click-once application version? IE: I have published version 1, and then I publish 1.1. On the first launch of version 1.1 I would like to perform a one time process when it's launching.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this:

```
 if(System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed && System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsFirstRun)
 {
    //do something
 }
```

About IsFirstRun from msdn:

> Type: System.Boolean
>   true if this version of the application has never run on the client computer before; otherwise, false.

Comment: Will IsFirstRun be true after a click-once update, or only initial install? I'll try to check.

Comment: +1; wasn't aware of this, but this looks like exactly what the OP's asking for.

Comment: Be aware that I have had issues with this before. It may or may not work when using automatic versioning, if the user clicks for the update himself without using built-in updating. This question is a similar story: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811780/how-do-i-detect-the-first-time-a-clickonce-deployed-application-has-been-run

Comment: They changed IsFirstRun. Needs to be called like this now: System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to store the application version (`ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion`) in a configuration value. If the number is different from the configuration value when you launch, then you know that it's been upgraded (or downgraded, but that should be easy enough to determine).

Comment: Good point, I could store it in a user type setting, and then do the comparison on launch, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to. We rely on IsFirstRun, and it has never failed us.