# Ask the user to restart pc/machine after clickonce install

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce

I can't seem to find a way to do this. I tried looking on publish options on visual studio but there seems to be no way via visual studio. I also tried searching but all I stumbled on was restarting the application after install not the machine/pc. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing that requires a restart? ClickOnce just copies files to the user's profile folder. That shouldn't ever require a restart.

Comment: I have a sqlce database on my application. I have a problem during first install or update of my application my data is not being saved when I try to save some data on my database. But when I try to restart my machine and try saving. The saving works.

Answer (score 0):

Move the restart check to your application startup code. You can [check if it is the first time the app has been run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811780) and prompt the user to reset.

It will be much easier to handle in your own code than to try and find a way to force ClickOnce to do it.