# How do I set Clickonce application to ignore actions on after first run?

Tags: c#, settings, clickonce

I have set: `Settings.Default.FirstRun = True;` by default.
Then, once the registry is created for my application, I change this value to             `Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;`

However, it seems whenever I do my actions on the application, it reverts to using the default.

See the code below:

```
private static void CheckFirstRun()
{
     if (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun == true)
     {

         string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
         RegisterMyProtocol(args[0]);

         Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
         Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

     }
}


static void Main()
{

     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     if (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun == true)
     {
         //   Call.Connection();    
         CheckFirstRun();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another article that I have now used to resolve. I have now included a text file on first install and delete on first instance.
[How do I detect the first time a ClickOnce-deployed application has been run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811780/how-do-i-detect-the-first-time-a-clickonce-deployed-application-has-been-run)